# How to parse and preserve text formatting (Python-Docx)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-docx, superscript

I'm using Python-Docx to export all the data from a 500-page Docx file into a spreadsheet using pandas. So far so good except that the process is removing all character styles. I have written the following to preserve superscript, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
for para in document.paragraphs:
    content = para.text

    for run in para.runs:
        if run.font.superscript:
            r.font.superscript = True

        r = para.add_run(run.text)
        scripture += r.text
```

My Input text might me, for example:

> Genesis 1:1 <sup>1</sup> In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

But my output into the Xlsx file is:

`Genesis 1:1 1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.` (Still losing the superscript formatting).

How do I preserve the `font.style` of each run for export? Perhaps more specifically, how do I get the text formatting from each run to be encoded into the "scripture" string?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot encode font information in a `str` object. A `str` object is a sequence of characters and that's that. It cannot indicate "make these five characters **bold** and the following three characters *italic*. There's just no place to put that sort of thing and the `str` data type is not made for that job.

Font (character-formatting) information must be stored in a container object of some sort. In Word, that's a *run*. It HTML it can be a `<span>` element. If you want character-formatting in your spreadsheet, you'll need to know how character formatting is stored in the target format (Excel maybe) and then apply it to text in that export format on a run-by-run basis.

There are some other problems with your code you should be aware of:

- the `r` in `r.font.superscript = True` is being used before being defined. The `r = para.add_run(run.text)` line would need to appear *prior* to that line to avoid problems. I wouldn't bother here because it's not actually doing anything here it turns out, but names need to be defined before use.
- You are doubling the size of the source paragraph by adding runs to it. This part actually contributes nothing because you then call `run.text` which as we mentioned cannot contain any character-formatting information and so it gets stripped back out.

The same result as your current code can be achieved by this:

```
scripture = "".join(p.text for p in document.paragraphs)
```

but I think you'll at approach like:

1. Parse out bits that go in separate cells
2. Within the text that goes into a single cell, write a "rich-text" cell something like that described here for XlsxWriter: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html